# Loop over ID in ggplot2, then save each plot individually

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, plot

I have a large dataframe in long format that contains about 13k rows. Here is example data of what it looks like.

```
# make data
set.seed(1234)
id <- c(101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,
        102,102,102,102,102,102,
        103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,103)
time <- c(1:9, 1:6, 1:11) 
var1 <- sample(1:20, 26, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id,time,var1)
```

I want to:

1. Generate a list of plots with x=time and y=var1 for each id
2. Save each id's plot individually as an image to a folder

My code so far is:

```
# loop to make plots
library(tidyverse)
id <- unique(df$id)
for(i in id){
  list <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = time, y = var1)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth() +
    ggtitle("Plot for", paste(df$id))
  print(list)
}

# loop to save plots
filename <- paste("plot_", df$id, ".png")
path <- "~/test"
for(i in list){
  ggsave(filename = filename, plot = plot[[i]], path = path)
}
```

The code to make a list of ggplots runs without errors, but whenever I try to view the list, it only shows the plot for id 101. The code save the list of plots results in an error: `Error: device must be NULL, a string or a function.` How should the code be fixed to achieve both goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data into list and use `map` to save each plot as an image.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(id) %>%
  map(~ggsave(sprintf('plot_%d.png', first(.x$id)), 
              ggplot(.x, aes(x = time, y = var1)) +
               geom_point() +
              stat_smooth() +  ggtitle(paste0("Plot for ", first(.x$id)))))
```

The first plot is tilted `plot_101.png` and looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your script is overwriting list on each iteration of the loop. It would be easier to save the plot when it is created.

But if you would like to store the plot created on each iteration for use later in the script, I suggest creating a list object outside the loop and then append objects on each iteration.
See the comments for more details.

```
# Create an empty list
plotlist <- list()

id <- unique(df$id)
for(i in id){
   #filter the dataframe for each id
   list <- df %>% filter(id==i) %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = var1)) +
      geom_point() +
      stat_smooth() +
      ggtitle("Plot for", paste(i))
   #print the plot
   print(list)
   #store the plot in the list with id as the name
   plotlist[[as.character(i)]] <- id
}
```

Now one can this list: "plotlist" for additional analysis later on.